# Set WinForms RichTextBox as the source of a PrintDocument

Tags: c#, .net, richtextbox, printdocument

I want to print the contents of a [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx), so I am trying make a [PrintDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx) out of the RichTextBox. But I dont find a way to convert a simple RichTextBox to a PrintDocument. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's quite an extensive article on this on MSDN, [Getting WYSIWYG Print Results from a .NET RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996492.aspx): if that's TLDR then there's a condensed version as a kb article, [How to print the content of a RichTextBox control by using Visual C# .NET or Visual C# 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812425)

Comment: the second one looks more compact. will try. but there should've been an implicit way. if not RTB, what are people supposed to print in a DotNet app?