# C#: in the .NET libraries, is there a standard class that can view and print an RTF string?

Tags: c#, winforms

C#: in the .NET libraries, is there a standard class that can view and print an RTF string?

I essentially need a "viewer" which will simply display a simple or rich-text string and have a print button which would allow printing of the displayed string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx) and set the [Rtf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf.aspx) member.

Regarding printing you can see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268328/set-winforms-richtextbox-as-the-source-of-a-printdocument) where there are some useful links:

- [Getting WYSIWYG Print Results from a .NET RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996492.aspx)
- [How to print the content of a RichTextBox control by using Visual C# .NET or Visual C# 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812425)